# Add _id to the source as a separate field to all exist docs in index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I'm new to Elastic Search. I need go through all the documents, take the `_id` and add it to the `_source` as a separate field by script. Is it possible? If yes, сan I have an example of something similar or a link to similar *scripts*? I haven't seen anything like that on the docks. Why i need it? - Because after that i will do SELECT with Opendistro and SQL. This frame cannot return me fields witch not in source. If anyone can suggest I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

**First option**: Add this new field in your existing index and populate it and build the new index again.

**Second option:** Simply define a new field in a new index mapping(keep rest all field same) and than use [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) with below script.

```
 "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.<your-field-name> = ctx._id"
    }
```

Comment: POST index/_doc/_update_by_query

`{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.docId = ctx._id"
    }
}`

Exactly what I need, thanks!